# Batch converting videos in folders and sub folders

Tags: bash, loops

I have a huge collection of videos that all need to be converted into mp4. The folder structure is like this

```
Events
  Chicago
  Boston
  San Fran
  London Expo
```

Inside each event holds all of videos in either avi format or .mkv. I want them to be converted to the same file name. but with the mp4 extension.

My question is how do I loop through a folders sub folders, and also keep the file names because at the moment they have spaces in them.. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
sourcedir="$1"
destdir="$2"
cd "$sourcedir"
for i in `ls`; do
  HandBrakeCLI -i "$i" -o "$destdir/${i%.*}.mp4" --preset="AppleTV"
  echo $i
done
```

Phillips Code:

```
cd "$sourcedir"
echo "Directory: $sourcedir"
destdir = sourcedir
for subdir in *
do
  if [[ -d "$subdir" ]]
  then
    for file in "$subdir"/*
    do
      HandBrakeCLI -i "$file" -o "${file%.*}.mp4" --preset=AppleTV
      echo "$file"
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: 1. Avoid using `cd` without checking—use `set -e` or `cd || exit 1`, or, even better, don’t change the directory at all; otherwise your script could operate in the wrong directory. 2. `destdir = sourcedir` is not an assignment but will try to call a command named `destdir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested loop, and don't use `ls`:

```
for subdir in "$sourcedir"/*
do
  if [[ -d "$subdir" ]]
  then
    for file in "$subdir"/*
    do
      HandBrakeCLI -i "$file" -o "$destdir/${file%.*}.mp4" --preset=AppleTV
      echo "$file"
    done
  fi
done
```

Another option is to use `find`:

```
find "$sourcedir" -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -exec bash -c 'HandBrakeCLI -i "$0" -o "'"$destdir"'/${0%.*}.mp4" --preset=AppleTV' '{}' ';' -print
```

Both solutions will work with filenames containing spaces or newlines.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked perfectly, I had a few corrupted avis!

Answer (score 1):

Either use `for i in "$sourcedir/*"` (or since you've already done a `cd` there you could do `for i in *`).

or do `find "$sourcedir" -type f | while read -r i` (with this, the variable `i` will include the source directory name, so you'll have to strip that off using a brace expansion or `basename`).

Answer (score 1):

change program to iVI [link to iVi](http://southpolesoftware.com/iVI/iVI.php).

this program does the trcik, even better than handbrake...

Answer (score 0):

bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
destdir="/somewhere"
for file in **/*.mkv **/*.avi
do
  HandBrakeCLI -i "$file" -o "$destdir/${file%.*}.mp4" --preset=AppleTV
done
```